# Obtaining threshold based rules for classification problem

Tags: classification, decision-trees, data-science-model, binary-classification

Suppose there are X1...Xn numerical variables predicting a target variable Y (0 or 1)

**Objective**: to obtain the best possible thresholds and combinations of X1...Xn that can predict Y

**Example**: (X1>60 and X3<20) predicts Y=1 with 90% accuracy

**Approach**: Train a decision tree and select the conditions leading upto leaf nodes with high "purity"

**Question 1**: Is there a name for this process for generating threshold based rules by combination of variables?

**Question 2**: Are there better alternatives to decision tree for this process?